# How to fix "but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable" error in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony4

I build a management app of bagages and voyages with Symfony 4, I created a "**ManyToMany**" relation between this entities.

When I want to add a new bagage with a destination (voyage) I have this error :

[image: screen]

I have **addVoyage** and **removeVoyage** in my classes Voyage and Bagage.

You will find above my classes **Bagage.php**, my form **BagageType.php** and my controller **BagageController.php**

***Bagage.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BagageRepository")
 */
class Bagage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=50)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
     */
    private $objets = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Voyage", mappedBy="bagages")
     */
    private $voyages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->voyages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getObjets(): ?array
    {
        return $this->objets;
    }

    public function setObjets(?array $objets): self
    {
        $this->objets = $objets;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreation(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateCreation;
    }

    public function setDateCreation(\DateTimeInterface $dateCreation): self
    {
        $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Voyage[]
     */
    public function getVoyages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->voyages;
    }

    public function addVoyage(Voyage $voyage): self
    {
        if (!$this->voyages->contains($voyage)) {
            $this->voyages[] = $voyage;
            $voyage->addBagage($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeVoyage(Voyage $voyage): self
    {
        if ($this->voyages->contains($voyage)) {
            $this->voyages->removeElement($voyage);
            $voyage->removeBagage($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
?>
```

**BagageType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Voyage;
use App\Entity\Bagage;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BagageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('voyages', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Voyage::class,
                'choice_label' => 'lieu'
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Bagage::class,
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

**BagageController.php**

```
<?php
/**
     * @Route("/bagages/nouveau", name="bagage_creation")
     * @Route("/bagages/{id}/edit", name="bagage_edit")
     */
    public function form(Bagage $bagage = null, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        if(!$bagage){
            $bagage = new Bagage();
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(BagageType::class, $bagage);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if(!$bagage->getId()){
                $bagage->setDateCreation(new \Datetime());
            }

            $manager->persist($bagage);
            $manager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('bagage_show', [
                'id' => $bagage->getId()
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('bagages/create.html.twig', [
            //creation d'une vue pour twig pour afficher le formulaire
            'formBagage' => $form->createView(),
            'editMode' => $bagage->getId() !== null
        ]);
    }
?>
```

***Does it miss an addVoyage call in my controller ?***

**EDIT**

**Voyage.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VoyageRepository")
 */
class Voyage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lieu;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bagage", inversedBy="voyages")
     */
    private $bagages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bagages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLieu(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lieu;
    }

    public function setLieu(string $lieu): self
    {
        $this->lieu = $lieu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Bagage[]
     */
    public function getBagages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bagages;
    }

    public function addBagage(Bagage $bagage): self
    {
        if (!$this->bagages->contains($bagage)) {
            $this->bagages[] = $bagage;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBagage(Bagage $bagage): self
    {
        if ($this->bagages->contains($bagage)) {
            $this->bagages->removeElement($bagage);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should set `multiple` attribute to true, making the field's value an array instead of a single entity.

```
        ->add('voyages', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Voyage::class,
            'choice_label' => 'lieu',
            'multiple' => true,
        ]);
```

Comment: I test to add your code 'multiple' => true and i have no error but when i submit my form, my bagage don't have any Voyage in database, as if my addVoyage method was not working.

Comment: If I persist $voyage, this will create a new Voyage in database. But I just want to change the voyage of my bagage by an other existant.

Comment: Can you add the relation mapping from the Voyage side to your question?

Comment: Yes of course, I edit my post with the Voyage class's.